# Redirecting to/rendering AngularJS2 page from Spring boot back-end application using ModelAndView object

Tags: spring, angular

I am new to Angular and I am facing some issues passing arguments to Angular screen from my backend Spring application.

In my Spring application, I am returning a `ModelAndView` object like this:

Spring boot application:

```
// .....
ModelAndView myMv = new ModelAndView();
myMv.setViewName("index.html"); // this is my angular js2 bootstrap index.html.
myMv.addObject("txn_id", txn_id);
// .....
return myMv;
```

Angular app:
In: `index.html` (Angular bootstrap screen)

```
ngInit() {  
    // will be called on page load
    let txn_id = this._route.SNAPSHOT.params["txn_id"];
    // here txn_id is undefined.
    // .....
}
```

Here, an API/URL is directly called from browser [not from any other screen] which invokes a service in the backend application. The backend service returns `ModelAndView` object with `index.html` as its view component.

How do I get the arguments in the Angular screen?

Comment: AngularJS is not Angular, you should clarify whether you are using one or the other. See [AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info) and [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info)

Comment: I am using AngularJS2.